# VI read line not giving desired output

Tags: vim, vi

I have a file called `test`, I open it using vi as such:

```
vi test
```

Now I want to insert a line through a shell command, for simplicity I use a `printf`:

```
:r! printf %s hello
```

However the line that is entered is

```
tests
```

i.e. the name of the file with a `s` appended.

If I enter the same command in terminal directly, it works fine.

What I want to do is ultimately be able to encode a string in base64 and enter it on the same line as where my cursor is in vi, so that I won't have to copy the string in a separate terminal, encode it, and copy it back into vi. How can I do this? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first stage of processing a command line in `vim` is [`expand`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#expand())ing it. `%` is expanded to the name of the current file — `test` in your case. `%s` is expanded to `tests`.

To avoid expanding protect the special character with a backslash:

```
:r! printf \%s hello
```